# Google places autocomplete Angular directive not working on touch devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to work with Google Places' auto complete to create an input that auto completes city names. The autocomplete field is suppose to select a city when tapped form the autocomplete list. It works fine on Desktop but not on mobile devices. When I select the city I want, it does not hide the auto complete list or set the city as the value of the input.

My directive looks as follows:

angular.module('googlePlacesAutocomplete', [])
    .directive('gPlacesAutocomplete', gPlacesAutocomplete);

```
function gPlacesAutocomplete ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: postLink
    }

    function postLink (scope, element, attrs, ngModel ) {
        var options = {
            types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: {}
        };

        var autocoplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0]);
        autocoplete.setTypes(options.types);

        autocoplete.addListener('place_changed', function(evt) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());  
            }); 
        });

        ngModel.$render = function() {
            element.val(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };       
    }
}
```

I have seen many solutions that suggest adding the following event to the directive will fix the issue:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
    angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
    angular.element(container).on("click", function(event){
        element.blur();
    }); },500);
```

I have tried it but it does not fix the issue. Once I added this solution the auto complete hide, but the model is not updated with the selected city. I am using Angular Material along with the API.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
     <md-input-container class="md-block">
           <label>From</label>
           <input g-places-autocomplete autocomplete="off" id="origin" ng-focus="vm.disableTap('origin')" type="text" name="origin" ng-model="vm.query.origin">
      </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Can anyone provide any more insight? What am I missing. I have read many post that attribute this to fast click.

You can view a live example and try it on mobile at [Trypp.com](http://www.trypp.com/)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: in what way does it "not work" - please describe the problem a little better than just "not work"

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, I updated my questions. Thank you!

Comment: It's seems like you fixed the problem, @jose-carrillo. I tested Trypp.com on my iPhone and it works. Please consider to post an answer and mark it as solved. Other people may have the same problem (like me...)

Comment: I upgraded the app to Angular. The original question was for AngularJS.